# why does Java’s JIT compilation happen within user threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, jit, zgc

I’m working with ZGC in Java JDK17, and I’ve been looking into some long-running requests where I can’t figure out where some of the time is going. When I checked the GC logs, I saw that the thread IDs for jit,compilation were from user threads, and the timing lined up with when those slow requests were happening. I’m wondering why jit,compilation is happening on user threads and why it seems to be holding up the user threads.

There is gc log below:
579 is Java-Compiler thread,  4236 is user thread.

```
[2024-03-27T10:26:37.675+0800][579 ][jit,compilation] 27257       3       java.net.InetAddress::getAllByName (388 bytes)   made not entrant
[2024-03-27T10:26:38.572+0800][579 ][jit,compilation] 46702       4       Script_1711505411710_68000::execute0 (112 bytes)
[2024-03-27T10:26:38.576+0800][579 ][jit,compilation] 39531       3       Script_1711505411710_68000::execute0 (112 bytes)   made not entrant
[2024-03-27T10:26:38.716+0800][4236][jit,compilation] 42949   !   4       com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment::get (122 bytes)   made not entrant
[2024-03-27T10:26:38.716+0800][4236][jit,compilation] 35244       4       com.google.common.cache.LocalCache::isExpired (57 bytes)   made not entrant
[2024-03-27T10:26:38.716+0800][4236][jit,compilation] 28530       4       com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment::recordRead (29 bytes)   made not entrant
```

I did some research and found out that `made not entrant` means it’s doing JIT deoptimization, I’m wondering if jit deoptimization could take so long? What’s it doing all that time, and how can we avoid it?

Comment: So as to make them faster later on.

Comment: So, because something happens at the same time, you conclude that it must happen in the same thread? Letting aside that these log entries do not allow any conclusion about the thread(s), these operations were performed in, letting aside that the operation is not compilation but “[made not entrant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2930838/2711488)”; if A and B happen at the same time, you can not conclude that A causes B, it might as well be that B causes A or that both are the result of a common cause C or still happen at the same time by coincidence.

Comment: The logs *do* refer to application thread IDs, but this does not yet mean application threads are doing JIT compilation. This could be the reverse, though - when application threads are involved in deoptimization ("made not entrant" is an indirect sign of that, although deoptimization is not the only reason while compiled methods may be marked as not entrant).

Comment: @Holger Sorry I forgot to mention, I used jstack and found that thread id 4236 is the one handling that slow request.

Comment: @apangin I’m wondering if jit deoptimization could take so long? What’s it doing all that time, and how can we avoid it?

Comment: How long is "so long"?